# Symfony 2.8: CollectionType - do not delete old entries

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I want to submit a form, each time I want a new entries being added to a database, but do not delete old ones.

Let's say I have an inventory entity, which contains a serial numbers collection.

Inventory form builder

```
$builder
    ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class)
    ->add('inventorySerialNumbers', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => InventorySerialNumberType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => false,
        'by_reference' => false,
    ))
;
```

Inventory serial number property:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InventorySerialNumber", mappedBy="inventory", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $inventorySerialNumbers;
```

So, I want to create a new inventory - I send a `quantity` and 2 `inventorySerialNumbers` and all data is being added correctly. But if I want to add one more entry, I will send a quantity 1 and one `inventorySerialNumbers`  item, as a result I will get only one latest entry stored in the database.

Seems that Symfony ignoring `cascade={"persist"}` and `'allow_delete' => false`

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry for the delay, after hours of research I found that entries were not deleted, but replaced with new ones. Solution, that was appropriate for me, is to send complete collection of items each time form submitted.

Comment: Good to know you fixed the problem. So when a user adds a new item, you merge it with the existing items?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I should keep items order each time I submit the form to prevent rewriting old items with new ones/

Comment: Consider changing that part. What if you add constraints (no duplicate serial numbers for example) and someone adds an existing number? I don't know what your code is exactly doing, but possibly you're bypassing validation.

Answer (score 1):

A Form action will add or modify an entity. In this case, I think you're overwriting an entity instead of creating a new one (option 1) or modifying an existing one (option 2).

## Option 1: add new items only

Create [a simple form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html) that will add a `Inventory`. A user will fill in the form and creates a new `Inventory`. After submitting the form, you will end up with two records in your database. If you want to know how many items you have, you have to sum up those values.

## Option 2: allow users to modify items

If you want to allow your users to delete serial numbers or lower the quantity, you'll havo to create a `editAction`. Unfortunately I couldn't find a good example on Symfony's website, but here are two recources you should look at:

- [Easy Edit Form](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-forms/easy-edit-form)
- [Generating a CRUD Controller Based on a Doctrine Entity](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html)